# UPPAAL SMC motivating example

Tags: model, model-checking, uppaal

I want to understand the UPPAAL SMC example discussed in [1].

Here is the UPPAAL-SMC example:

[image: UPPAAL-SMC example]

The three timed automata should visualize the probability distribution in UPPAAL SMC. In the paper it is indicated that the END-locations of the three TAs can be reached within the time intervals [6,12], [4,12] and [0,+∞). I modeled the A1 TA in UPPAAL and there is no possibility to reach the END location because of the update X=0 and the guard x >= 2 in the edges. 
How the time-intervals are calculated in detail?

[1] http://people.cs.aau.dk/~kgl/SSFT2015/SMC%20tutorial.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A1**: is comprised by four states `s1, s2, s3, s4 = END`. The amount of time that can be spent inside `s1` is lower-bounded by the guard `x >= 2` and upper-bounded by the label `x <= 4`. The same holds for `s2` and `s3`. Hence, the time interval for **A1** is `[2 + 2 + 2, 4 + 4 + 4] = [6, 12]`.

**A2**: is comprised by two paths `s1, s2, s3, s4, s5 = END` and `s1, s6, s7, s5 = END`. The first path is the same as **A1**. The time interval of the second path is `[4, 8]`. Overall, the time interval for **A2** is `[min(6, 4), max(12, 8)] = [4, 12]`.

**A3**: there are no time labels nor guards, hence the time interval is `[0, +oo]`, assuming the existence of some time variable.